# В SASS не работают подсказки(autocopmlete)

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, плагин, autocomplete, hint

Я уже все мозги себе вы**** простите)). В sass приходится писать все в ручную, без выпадающих подсказок(autocopmlete, вроде называются, не суть =) ). После того как пишу вложенность допустим, &_subtitle пропадают все подсказки и даже когда удаляю вложенность, все равно их нету. 
**Плагин- Sass  (установлен)** 
Когда писал в .scss такого ни разу не было, все чётко было. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

- Откройте настройки редактора (Preferences -> Settings).
- Добавьте следующую строку в файл настроек:

```
"auto_complete": true
```